# Java Generic Type and Object Class

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I need to know what is the difference between java Generic type and Object class. Here are two codes and both works fine, I just need to know what is the difference between them :

Program 1 using Object Class:
    package a;

```
public class Generic {
    private Object[] datastore;
    private int size;
    private int pos;

    public Generic(int numEl) {
        size = numEl;
        pos = 0;
        datastore = new Object[size];
    }

    public void add(Object a){
        datastore[pos] = a;
        pos++;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String elements ="";
        for (int i=0; i<pos; i++) {
            elements += datastore[i] + " ";
        }

        return elements;
    }
}
```

Program 2 using Generic Type:
    package a;

```
public class Generic<T> {
    private T[] datastore;
    private int size;
    private int pos;

    public Generic(int numEl){
        size = numEl;
        pos = 0;
        datastore = (T[]) new Object[size];
    }

    public void add(T a) {
        datastore[pos] = a;
        pos++;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String elements ="";
        for (int i=0; i<pos; i++) {
            elements += datastore[i] + " ";
        }

        return elements;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Google Java generics.  The Sun/Oracle trails give a great basic coverage of this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genercis is `compile` time concept to ensure `type safety`. At `runtime`

```
private T[] datastore;
```

will be interpreted as

```
private Object[] datastore;
```

So you can say

```
Generic generic = new Generic(2);
generic.add("test"); //allowed
```

but you cannot say

```
Generic<Integer> generic = new Generic<Integer>(2);
generic.add("test");  // compiler error
```

Comment: But only if instantiated with T as Object, obviously.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it will be same at runtime irrespective of Generic type you provide, not just Object. Generics help in type safety at compile time.

Comment: Yea, I know that. So you mean to say that the only difference b/w those two is, in case of Generic type, there is a safety switch that only allows the particular type of data to be entered?

Comment: yes precisely. You know that the input you want from your user is String and store in List. If you do not provide any generic argument or Object then user can add any value (not just String) and your processing logic will go wrong there after. To prevent it you need to enable type safety by using generics.

Answer (score 3):

Due to [*Type Erasure*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens), the technique used to implement generics in Java, there is no difference between these code snippets at runtime.

However, at compile time the second code snippet provides better code safety.

For example, it ensures that all objects inside the array `datastore` have the same type. The first snippet lets you add objects of different type to `datastore`, because all objects derive from `Object`. The second snippet, however, requires that all calls to `add` were supplying objects compatible with type `T`, the generic type parameter of the class.

Answer (score 1):

When `type erasure` begins, compiler replaces all parameters to it top bounds. For example:

`class Example<T> {}`

will become

`class Example<Object> {}`

If you define parameter with bounds, it will be something like that:

```
class Example<T extends Number> {}
```

will become

```
class Example<Number> {}
```

Essentially, your two examples are generic: one with a pre-defined type `"Object"`, and the second one with `T extends Object` type which is more concrete and secured than the first one. With the latter, you avoid unnecessary casts